# How to send AWS SNS notification between mobile device endpoint in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, endpoint

I need to send SNS notification from an Android mobile device targeting another specific Android device endpoint. I could do this last year with the code below. Now it just doesn't work any more. Does anyone have similar issues with sending SNS notification to specific mobile endpoint and how can it be resolved?

```
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new    AmazonSNSClient(identityManager.getCredentialsProvider());

    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
                publishRequest.setMessage(message);
                publishRequest.setSubject(subject);
                publishRequest.withTargetArn(mobilePhoneEndpointARN);
                snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Yes, I later saw the error pointing me towards providing a custom sns publish permission for the user group policy. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. I added a custom "sns:Publish" permission to my authenticated mobile user policy group.
-Problem solved-

Comment: are you getting the message in the recipient device with a "default tag?